# Unable to run python script in c# which runs scrapy spider

Tags: c#, python, web-scraping, scrapy

I followed [this_link](https://medium.com/@dpursanov/running-python-script-from-c-and-working-with-the-results-843e68d230e5) and I was able to run a dummy python file from my c# code like this...

```
   public JsonResult FetchscrapyDataUrl(String website)
        {

           ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = @"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe";            
            start.Arguments = @"C:\Users\PycharmProjects\scraping_web\scrape_info\main.py";
           //this is path to .py file from scrapy project

            start.CreateNoWindow = false;  // We don't need new window
            start.UseShellExecute = false;  // Do not use OS shell
            //start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;// Any output, generated by application will be redirected back
            start.RedirectStandardError = true; // Any error in standard output will be redirected back (for example exceptions)
            Console.WriteLine("Python Starting");
       

            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // Here are the exceptions from our Python script
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();  // Here is the result of StdOut(for example: print "test")
                    Console.Write(result);
                }
            }
    
    }
```

Now I know that I can run [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) spider from a single file `main.py` like this...

```
from scrapy import cmdline    
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl text".split())
```

When I run main.py file from cmd in windows it works fine but it does not work when I run it from C# code .Net framework. The error is ...

```
"Scrapy 1.4.0 - no active project\r\n\r\nUnknown command: crawl\r\n\r\nUse \"scrapy\" to see available commands\r\n"
```

Any Idea how to run this...**Or am i missing some path setting in windows** ??

**Or should I run my spider from C# in some other way??**

Comment: Instead, use scrapyd API to run your scrapers, https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ ... you just need to send a POST request to run a scraper, and I believe how you send a POST request in C# (I am not C# programmer otherwise I would have told you)

Comment: Thanks for the reply...can you give me an overview of post request in any language you are comfortable with....

Comment: Basically this is the cURL command to start a spider, `curl` command `curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=spider2 -d anyOtherExtraParam="Value Here"` You can copy and paste that command in this tool https://curl.trillworks.com/ here and you will have the converted code in Python/PHP

Comment: can I use this scrapyd API using javascript?and do i need to deploy my project on cloud for this?

Comment: I looked at your question again and I saw your error `Scrapy 1.4.0 - no active project`,,, that occurs if you are not in directory where your scrapy project exists, I suggest you to first execute `cd /path/to/your/project/` in your C# code or in your `main.py`

Comment: thank you...you are right ....cd to path....solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `WorkingDirectory` property

```
start.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\PycharmProjects\scraping_web\scrape_info\"
```

Or you need to cd to that directory to make it work